# Checking Greek declensions: software or reference?

Tags: greek, declension

Although quite a few Greek words follow the same simple patterns of declension, I'm finding that there are enough complications that I'm often unsure of whether I'm getting it right. Is there a reference work that I could check against? Software would also be fine, but I would be looking for something open-source that can be run on linux.

I found this software: https://github.com/jtauber/greek-inflexion . It looks like it might be nice for this purpose, but it seemed nontrivial to install.

I would happily pay money for the equivalent of "500 Spanish Verbs," but for Greek nouns. Or maybe if there is some smaller number of patterns, like 20 patterns or something, it would be enough to see just those patterns laid out.

Comment: Are you interested in noun/adjective declension or verb conjugation? In Greek, one is significantly easier than the other!

Comment: @Draconis: I meant noun declensions. Which do you think is harder?

Comment: Verbs, by orders of magnitude. Nouns are way easier.